# resolved: c++ : put normal method definition into source file while the templates method in header file

Tags: c++, templates

Since the definition of template must be put in header file,  so I don't like it if the template class is big.  so I want to make a normal class with some templated methods. Putting the defintion of templated method into header file, for others, put them into c++ source files.  So here is what I am thinking.

```
// lambda.h
#include <iostream>
class X {
 public:
  std::function<bool(int)> filter;
  template <class F>
  void setFilter(F fn) {
    filter = fn;
  }
  void big_function(int x);
};

// cat lambda.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "lambda.h"

void X::big_function(int x) {
  if (filter(x)) std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
// main2.cpp
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "lambda.h"

class Filter {
 public:
  bool operator()(int x) { return true; }
};

int main() {
  X x;
  x.setFilter(Filter());
  x.big_function(3);
  return 0;
}
// cat 2.sh
g++ -c lambda.cpp -ggdb
g++ -c  main2.cpp  -ggdb -std=c++11
g++ -o main2 main2.o lambda.o -ggdb
```

this program can compile, but got segment fault during executing (x.big_function(3));

@update 
Q1: is my thinking is reasonable?  is there any obvious error in my code? 
Answer: Yes, it is reasonable, and no obvious error. Thanks to the first 4 comments,  I did more test and works.

Q2: actually if I compile with -std=c++11, I will got segment fault.  but no segment fault if I don't use std=c++11.  ( I tried c++11 yesterday because I used lambda expression rather than function object for "Filter" at beginning). And it my real case, I can't discard c++11 features.
Answer:  shame about my fault.   fixed the issue by adding -std=c++11 for every compile unit.

```
zhifan$ sh -x 2.sh
+ g++ -c lambda.cpp -ggdb
+ g++ -c main2.cpp -ggdb
+ g++ -o main2 main2.o lambda.o -ggdb
zhifan$ ./main2
3
zhifan$ vim 2.sh
hifan$ sh -x 2.sh
+ g++ -c lambda.cpp -ggdb **-std=c++11**
+ g++ -c main2.cpp -ggdb -std=c++11
+ g++ -o main2 main2.o lambda.o -ggdb
zhifan$ ./main2
Segmentation fault: 11
zhifan$ g++ -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: Your segmentation fault is unrelated to your implementation.

Comment: The first part of the question (before the code) seems completely unrelated to the part that is after the code

Comment: Try to narrow the problem to some code that you can show us without stripping it like you did. That way we can copy, compile and see for ourselves what is happening. (And it may explain a bit your rather unclear question)

Comment: I suggest you look for an error in `big_function`.

Comment: @Borgleader, that's related.  I want to "Putting the defintion of templated method into header file, for others, put them into c++ source files".  so I wrote the above code. But the code doesn't works.  So I want to know if it is possible to make it true for my intention, if my implement has some obvious error.

Comment: @Dettorer, Thanks. I will make sure my future question is easy to re-produce in future.  Update my question again.  Thanks for attention.  Thanks all of you.